# Are instances of Exception checked or unchecked exceptions?

Tags: java, exception

In Java, checked exceptions are all instances of `Throwable`, except the instances of `Error` and `RuntimeException`. More specifically, if a class extends `Exception`, but not `RuntimeException`, it will be considered a checked exception.

This is why, for `catch` blocks catching a checked exception, the compiler checks if it can be actually thrown from the `try` block and reports a compiler error if this isn't the case:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class ExceptionTest5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

```
ExceptionTest5.java:10: error: exception IOException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
```

which wouldn't be reported if `RuntimeException` was in the catch block.

However, **nothing is being reported if `Exception` or `Throwable` are in the catch block**, which makes them act like they were unchecked exceptions - which is directly opposed to the first sentence of this post, which I found in many different sources.

So, is `Exception` a checked or unchecked exception?

Comment: Instances of `Exception` are neither checked nor unchecked. The checking of exceptions happens at compile time, when there are no instances.

Comment: You are drawing the wrong conclusions. The error you see here is not directly because of checked-ness (or unchecked-ness), but rather because the compiler can guarantee (*) that exception won't be thrown in that block, so it would be redundant to catch it.

Comment: (*) it can't actually, because you can trick the compiler to turn checked exceptions into unchecked exceptions, using generics.